# Optimizing repetitive estimation (currently a loop) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, optimization, matrix, least-squares

I've found myself needing to do a least-squares (or similar matrix-based operation) for every pixel in an image. Every pixel has a set of numbers associated with it, and so it can be arranged as a 3D matrix.

(**This next bit can be skipped**)

Quick explanation of what I mean by least-squares estimation :

Let's say we have some quadratic system that is modeled by Y = Ax^2 + Bx + C and we're looking for those A,B,C coefficients. With a few samples (at least 3) of X and the corresponding Y, we can estimate them by:

1. Arrange the (lets say 10) X samples into a matrix like `X = [x(:).^2 x(:) ones(10,1)];`
2. Arrange the Y samples into a similar matrix: `Y = y(:);`
3. Estimate the coefficients A,B,C by solving: `coeffs = (X'*X)^(-1)*X'*Y;`

Try this on your own if you want:

```
A = 5; B = 2; C = 1;
x = 1:10;
y = A*x(:).^2 + B*x(:) + C + .25*randn(10,1); % added some noise here
X = [x(:).^2 x(:) ones(10,1)];
Y = y(:);
coeffs = (X'*X)^-1*X'*Y

coeffs =

  5.0040
  1.9818
  0.9241
```

**START PAYING ATTENTION AGAIN IF I LOST YOU THERE**

**MAJOR REWRITE**I've modified to bring it as close to the real problem that I have and still make it a minimum working example.

**Problem Setup**

```
%// Setup
xdim = 500; 
ydim = 500; 
ncoils = 8; 
nshots = 4; 
%// matrix size for each pixel is ncoils x nshots (an overdetermined system)

%// each pixel has a matrix stored in the 3rd and 4rth dimensions
regressor = randn(xdim,ydim, ncoils,nshots); 
regressand = randn(xdim, ydim,ncoils);
```

So my problem is that I have to do a (X'*X)^-1*X'*Y (least-squares or similar) operation for every pixel in an image. While that itself is vectorized/matrixized the only way that I have to do it for every pixel is in a for loop, like:

**Original code style**

```
%// Actual work
tic 
estimate = zeros(xdim,ydim);
for col=1:size(regressor,2)
    for row=1:size(regressor,1)

        X = squeeze(regressor(row,col,:,:));
        Y = squeeze(regressand(row,col,:));

        B = X\Y; 
        % B = (X'*X)^(-1)*X'*Y; %// equivalently

        estimate(row,col) = B(1);
    end
end
toc

Elapsed time = 27.6 seconds
```

**EDITS in reponse to comments and other ideas**
I tried some things:
1. Reshaped into a long vector and removed the double `for` loop. This saved some time.
2. Removed the `squeeze` (and in-line transposing) by `permute`-ing the picture before hand: This save alot more time.

**Current example:**

```
%// Actual work
tic 
estimate2 = zeros(xdim*ydim,1);
regressor_mod = permute(regressor,[3 4 1 2]);
regressor_mod = reshape(regressor_mod,[ncoils,nshots,xdim*ydim]);
regressand_mod = permute(regressand,[3 1 2]);
regressand_mod = reshape(regressand_mod,[ncoils,xdim*ydim]);

for ind=1:size(regressor_mod,3) % for every pixel

    X = regressor_mod(:,:,ind);
    Y = regressand_mod(:,ind);

    B = X\Y;

    estimate2(ind) = B(1);

end
estimate2 = reshape(estimate2,[xdim,ydim]);
toc

Elapsed time = 2.30 seconds (avg of 10)
isequal(estimate2,estimate) == 1;
```

**Rody Oldenhuis's way**

```
N  = xdim*ydim*ncoils;  %// number of columns
M  = xdim*ydim*nshots;    %// number of rows

ii = repmat(reshape(1:N,[ncoils,xdim*ydim]),[nshots 1]); %//column indicies
jj = repmat(1:M,[ncoils 1]); %//row indicies

X = sparse(ii(:),jj(:),regressor_mod(:));
Y = regressand_mod(:);

B = X\Y;

B = reshape(B(1:nshots:end),[xdim ydim]);

Elapsed time = 2.26 seconds (avg of 10) 
            or 2.18 seconds (if you don't include the definition of N,M,ii,jj)
```

**SO THE QUESTION IS:** 
**Is there an (even) faster way?**

(I don't think so.)

Comment: doesn't `svd` answer something like that?

Comment: I don't see how a SVD can be used to solve this problem.

Comment: @Frederick why are using psuedo inv `inv(X'*X)*X` instead of backslash (mldivide)?

Comment: @Frederick: Please complete your code. It seems impossible to put something for `Y` which makes `coeff(x,y)` a scalar

Comment: One simple things to possibly speed it up: permute the dimensions of `image` outside the loops (also don't call the variable `image`) to avoid calling `squeeze`. But without working code, I'm not going try further.

Comment: You could convert your many independent linear equations into one large linear equation with a [block-diagonal matrix](http://www.mathreference.com/la-jf,bdiag.html).  Such matrices, however, tend to have a low rank and may misbehave when trying to solve the inverse.  I'd recommend trying the two simple optimizations that were suggested above (mldivide and permutation) first, though.

Comment: @Shai no good reason. I changed just changed it `\`, tested it, and `\` is slightly slower than `^(-1)`, which I would not have expected. This was testing by coping and pasting into the Command Window - I'm not sure the JIT compiler works in that context.

Comment: I've responded to comments, and now it is much faster. The double loop accounted for ~1/3 of the speed-up and eliminating `squeeze` accounted for about ~2/3.

Comment: I agree with @MattB. If you ever have large data sets it would be worth your time to read John D'Errico's "optimtips" submission on File Exchange. It does a fantastic job of explaining (with examples) a lot of optimization tricks (such as batching).

Comment: @Frederick: Your 3rd edit broke the code. The variable "picture" is never set. When I use the line from your original code I get a dimension mismatch at `X(:,2)=picture(:,x);`.

Comment: @DanielR - Fixed.
Thanks everyone for thinking about this.

Comment: Still broken as picture is not defined.

Comment: Is there a better title for this post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Results

I sped up your *original* version, since your edit 3 was actually not working (and also does something different).

So, on my PC:

Your (original) version: **8.428473 seconds**.
My obfuscated one-liner given below: **0.964589 seconds**.

First, for no other reason than to impress, I'll give it as I wrote it:

```
%%// Some example data
xdim = 500; 
ydim = 500; 
n_timepoints = 10; % for example
estimate = zeros(xdim,ydim); %// initialization with explicit size

picture = randn(xdim,ydim,n_timepoints);


%%// Your original solution
%// (slightly altered to make my version's results agree with yours)

tic

Y = randn(n_timepoints,xdim*ydim);
ii = 1;
for x = 1:xdim
    for y = 1:ydim

        X = squeeze(picture(x,y,:)); %// or similar creation of X matrix

        B = (X'*X)^(-1)*X' * Y(:,ii);
        ii = ii+1;

        %// sometimes you keep everything and do
        %// estimate(x,y,:) = B(:);
        %// sometimes just the first element is important and you do
        estimate(x,y) = B(1);

    end
end

toc


%%// My version 

tic

%// UNLEASH THE FURY!!
estimate2 = reshape(sparse(1:xdim*ydim*n_timepoints, ...
    builtin('_paren', ones(n_timepoints,1)*(1:xdim*ydim),:), ...
    builtin('_paren', permute(picture, [3 2 1]),:))\Y(:), ydim,xdim).';  %'

toc

%%// Check for equality

max(abs(estimate(:)-estimate2(:)))  % (always less than ~1e-14)
```

### Breakdown

First, here's the version that you should *actually* use:

```
%// Construct sparse block-diagonal matrix
%// (Type "help sparse" for more information)
N  = xdim*ydim;      %// number of columns
M  = N*n_timepoints; %// number of rows
ii = 1:N;
jj = ones(n_timepoints,1)*(1:N);
s  = permute(picture, [3 2 1]);
X  = sparse(ii,jj(:), s(:));

%// Compute ALL the estimates at once
estimates = X\Y(:);

%// You loop through the *second* dimension first, so to make everything
%// agree, we have to extract elements in the "wrong" order, and transpose:
estimate2 = reshape(estimates, ydim,xdim).';  %'
```

Here's an example of what `picture` and the corresponding matrix `X` looks like for `xdim = ydim = n_timepoints = 2`:

```
>> clc, picture, full(X)

picture(:,:,1) =
   -0.5643   -2.0504
   -0.1656    0.4497
picture(:,:,2) =
    0.6397    0.7782
    0.5830   -0.3138

ans =
   -0.5643         0         0         0
    0.6397         0         0         0
         0   -2.0504         0         0
         0    0.7782         0         0
         0         0   -0.1656         0
         0         0    0.5830         0
         0         0         0    0.4497
         0         0         0   -0.3138
```

You can see why `sparse` is necessary -- it's mostly zeros, but will grow large quickly. The full matrix would quickly consume all your RAM, while the `sparse` one will not consume much more than the original `picture` matrix does.

With this matrix `X`, the new problem

```
X·b = Y
```

now contains *all* the problems

```
X1 · b1 = Y1
X2 · b2 = Y2
...
```

where

```
b = [b1; b2; b3; ...]
Y = [Y1; Y2; Y3; ...]
```

so, the single command

```
X\Y
```

will solve all your systems at once.

This offloads all the hard work to a set of highly specialized, compiled to machine-specific code, optimized-in-every-way algorithms, rather than the interpreted, generic, always-two-steps-away from the hardware loops in MATLAB.

It should be straightforward to convert this to a version where `X` is a matrix; you'll end up with something like what `blkdiag` does, which can also be used by `mldivide` in exactly the same way as above.

Comment: Why did you change the order of the first two dimensions when using `permute`? This creates an `X` matrix that goes across columns first, then rows, which works, of course, but is sort of against the matlab preference towards columns.

Comment: @Frederick to make the results agree with yours :) of course, with some minor tweaking this is easily corrected. Did you try this with X being a matrix yet?

Comment: I'm working on it now. I'm overhauling the example because it's a mess . This all-matrix was the the kind of solution I had in mind, though.

Comment: I wanted to show the implementation for may case, so I've added it as part of my question rather than edit this answer.

Comment: As a final follow-up: In the real-world use case, this is ~3x faster (2.97s to 0.94s). Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve a ~factor of 2 speed up by precomputing the transposition of X. i.e.

```
for x=1:size(picture,2) % second dimension b/c already transposed

    X = picture(:,x);
    XX = X';
    Y = randn(n_timepoints,1);
    %B = (X'*X)^-1*X'*Y; ;
    B = (XX*X)^-1*XX*Y; 
    est(x) = B(1);

end

Before: Elapsed time is 2.520944 seconds.
After: Elapsed time is 1.134081 seconds.
```

EDIT:
Your code, as it stands in your latest edit, can be replaced by the following

```
tic
xdim = 500; 
ydim = 500; 
n_timepoints = 10; % for example

% Actual work
picture = randn(xdim,ydim,n_timepoints);
picture = reshape(picture, [xdim*ydim,n_timepoints])'; % note transpose
YR = randn(n_timepoints,size(picture,2));

% (XX*X).^-1 = sum(picture.*picture).^-1;
% XX*Y = sum(picture.*YR);
est = sum(picture.*picture).^-1 .* sum(picture.*YR);

est = reshape(est,[xdim,ydim]);
toc

Elapsed time is 0.127014 seconds.
```

This is an order of magnitude speed up on the latest edit, and the results are all but identical to the previous method.

EDIT2:

Okay, so if X is a matrix, not a vector, things are a little more complicated. We basically want to precompute as much as possible outside of the for-loop to keep our costs down. We can also get a significant speed-up by computing `XT*X` manually - since the result will always be a symmetric matrix, we can cut a few corners to speed things up. First, the symmetric multiplication function:

```
function XTX = sym_mult(X) % X is a 3-d matrix

n = size(X,2);
XTX = zeros(n,n,size(X,3));
for i=1:n
    for j=i:n
        XTX(i,j,:) = sum(X(:,i,:).*X(:,j,:));
        if i~=j
            XTX(j,i,:) = XTX(i,j,:);
        end
    end
end
```

Now the actual computation script

```
xdim = 500; 
ydim = 500; 
n_timepoints = 10; % for example

Y = randn(10,xdim*ydim);
picture = randn(xdim,ydim,n_timepoints); % 500x500x10

% Actual work  
tic  % start timing

picture = reshape(picture, [xdim*ydim,n_timepoints])';

% Here we precompute the (XT*Y) calculation to speed things up later
picture_y = [sum(Y);sum(Y.*picture)]; 

% initialize
est = zeros(size(picture,2),1); 

picture = permute(picture,[1,3,2]);
XTX = cat(2,ones(n_timepoints,1,size(picture,3)),picture);
XTX = sym_mult(XTX); % precompute (XT*X) for speed

X = zeros(2,2); % preallocate for speed
XY = zeros(2,1);

for x=1:size(picture,2) % second dimension b/c already transposed

    %For some reason this is a lot faster than X = XTX(:,:,x);
    X(1,1) = XTX(1,1,x);
    X(2,1) = XTX(2,1,x);
    X(1,2) = XTX(1,2,x);
    X(2,2) = XTX(2,2,x);
    XY(1) = picture_y(1,x);
    XY(2) = picture_y(2,x);

    % Here we utilise the fact that A\B is faster than inv(A)*B
    % We also use the fact that (A*B)*C = A*(B*C) to speed things up
    B = X\XY;
    est(x) = B(1); 
end
est = reshape(est,[xdim,ydim]); 
toc % end timing

Before: Elapsed time is 4.56 seconds.
After: Elapsed time is 2.24 seconds.
```

This is a speed up of about a factor of 2. This code should be extensible to X being any dimensions you want. For instance, in the case where X = [1 x x^2], you would change `picture_y` to the following

```
picture_y = [sum(Y);sum(Y.*picture);sum(Y.*picture.^2)];
```

and change `XTX` to

```
XTX = cat(2,ones(n_timepoints,1,size(picture,3)),picture,picture.^2);
```

You would also change a lot of 2s to 3s in the code, and add `XY(3) = picture_y(3,x)` to the loop. It *should* be fairly straight-forward, I believe.

Comment: Ah, I need to edit my example. This will work very well when "X" is Nx1, but generally, X is a Nx(>1) matrix.

Comment: Ah right. I've made an amendment to my answer with some more enhancements.

Answer (score 3):

I had a wee play around with an idea, and I decided to stick it as a separate answer, as its a completely different approach to my other idea, and I don't actually condone what I'm about to do. I *think* this is the fastest approach so far:

Orignal (unoptimised): **13.507176 seconds**.
Fast Cholesky-decomposition method: **0.424464 seconds**

First, we've got a function to quickly do the `X'*X` multiplication. We can speed things up here because the result will always be symmetric.

```
function XX = sym_mult(X)

n = size(X,2);
XX = zeros(n,n,size(X,3));
for i=1:n
    for j=i:n
        XX(i,j,:) = sum(X(:,i,:).*X(:,j,:));
        if i~=j
            XX(j,i,:) = XX(i,j,:);
        end
    end
end
```

The we have a function to do LDL Cholesky decomposition of a 3D matrix (we can do this because the `(X'*X)` matrix will always be symmetric) and then do forward and backwards substitution to solve the LDL inversion equation

```
function Y = fast_chol(X,XY)

n=size(X,2);
L = zeros(n,n,size(X,3));
D = zeros(n,n,size(X,3));
B = zeros(n,1,size(X,3));
Y = zeros(n,1,size(X,3));
% These loops compute the LDL decomposition of the 3D matrix
for i=1:n
    D(i,i,:) = X(i,i,:);
    L(i,i,:) = 1;
    for j=1:i-1
        L(i,j,:) = X(i,j,:);
        for k=1:(j-1)
            L(i,j,:) = L(i,j,:) - L(i,k,:).*L(j,k,:).*D(k,k,:);
        end
        D(i,j,:) = L(i,j,:);
        L(i,j,:) = L(i,j,:)./D(j,j,:);
        if i~=j
            D(i,i,:) = D(i,i,:) - L(i,j,:).^2.*D(j,j,:);
        end
    end
end

for i=1:n
    B(i,1,:) = XY(i,:);
    for j=1:(i-1)
        B(i,1,:) = B(i,1,:)-D(i,j,:).*B(j,1,:);
    end
    B(i,1,:) = B(i,1,:)./D(i,i,:);
end

for i=n:-1:1
    Y(i,1,:) = B(i,1,:);
    for j=n:-1:(i+1)
        Y(i,1,:) = Y(i,1,:)-L(j,i,:).*Y(j,1,:);
    end
end
```

Finally, we have the main script which calls all of this

```
xdim = 500; 
ydim = 500; 
n_timepoints = 10; % for example

Y = randn(10,xdim*ydim);
picture = randn(xdim,ydim,n_timepoints); % 500x500x10

tic  % start timing

picture = reshape(pr, [xdim*ydim,n_timepoints])';
% Here we precompute the (XT*Y) calculation
picture_y = [sum(Y);sum(Y.*picture)];

% initialize
est2 = zeros(size(picture,2),1); 

picture = permute(picture,[1,3,2]);
% Now we calculate the X'*X matrix
XTX = cat(2,ones(n_timepoints,1,size(picture,3)),picture);
XTX = sym_mult(XTX);

% Call our fast Cholesky decomposition routine
B = fast_chol(XTX,picture_y);
est2 = B(1,:);

est2 = reshape(est2,[xdim,ydim]); 
toc
```

Again, this should work equally well for a Nx3 X matrix, or however big you want.

Comment: +1: an interesting idea indeed! But I do have a few questions: 1) the content of `est2` seems to differ from what I find, and what comes out of the OPs original version 2) why not loop over the 3rd dimension and call the built-in `chol` to do the decomposition?

Comment: 1) Ah, I probably messed up somewhere, it was bound to happen. OP has significantly changed how his original code looks anyway, so I'm not sure how relevant this is anymore. 2) It's actually much faster to do it my way than to do it the way you suggest - a quick test just now suggests that it could be as much as ~40x slower to loop it using the built-in method.

Answer (score 0):

I use octave, thus I can't say anything about the resulting performance in Matlab, but would expect this code to be slightly faster:

```
pictureT=picture'
est=arrayfun(@(x)( (pictureT(x,:)*picture(:,x))^-1*pictureT(x,:)*randn(n_ti
mepoints,1)),1:size(picture,2));
```